# Клонирование git и push в два репозитория

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-push, git-remote

Создал я локальный репозиторий у себя на компьютере:

```
cd /path/to/git/repo/
git init --bare --shared
```

В другом месте тоже инициализировал, с которым работал так, напрямую:

```
cd /path/to/my/project/
git init
echo "Helo" >> hello.txt
git add .
git commit -m "Init"
```

Вот теперь я хочу в свой локальный репозиторий сделать пуш:

```
git remote add origin /path/to/git/repo/
git push origin master
```

Все хорошо, все отлично. Если запустить эту команду в другой директории, он мне все скопирует, то есть сделает то, что я ожидаю:

```
cd /path/to/test/dir/
git clone /path/to/git/repo/
```

Теперь я хочу:

1. Все свои собранные коммиты запушить на свежий, только что созданный репозиторий в bitbucket.org.
2. Иметь возможность пушить как на битбакет, так и в локальный репозиторий

Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы добиться такого результата?

P.S. Отвечая на вопрос, зачем мне нужен локальный репозиторий. Мне нужно **всегда** иметь на компьютере копию проекта с учетом всех gitignore. **Даже** тогда, когда у меня нет интернета. Если есть возможность провернуть это без создания локального репозитория, можете дать совет. Но вопрос, как запушить все коммиты на битбакет и не видеть постоянные сообщения `Everything up-to-date` и другие, не смотря на то, что на компе у меня лежит целая куча нужных мне коммитов, остается открытым

Comment: вопрос «как запушить все коммиты» — это совершенно отдельная история. возможно, связанная с какой-то ошибкой. лучше задать по этому поводу новый вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

когда вы сделали `git init`, вы **уже** создали локальный репозиторий. он находится в под-каталоге `.git`.

файлы же, которые вы создали в этом каталоге (`/path/to/my/project/`), а затем с помощью `git add` и `git commit` «добавили в репозиторий», на самом деле представляют собой лишь *рабочую копию* содержимого репозитория.

репозиторий может быть и **без** *рабочей копии*. создаётся такой репозиторий при использовании опции `--bare` у команд `git clone`, `git init`. фактически вы получаете в таком репозитории то же содержимое, что и в каталоге `.git` у репозитория *с рабочей копией*.

поэтому создавать **ещё** одну локальную копию репозитория, как сделали вы в каталоге `/path/to/git/repo/`, нет необходимости. всё содержимое репозитория, все коммиты, вся история — доступны в любой из копий git-репозитория и **без** доступа к интернету. и коммиты в эту копию репозитория вы можете делать **без** доступа к интернету.

---

а как сделать вторую (третью, десятую) копию репозитория на каком-нибудь удалённом сервере, вы уже знаете:

```
$ git remote add ...
$ git push ...
```

---

о том, как одной командой `git push` отправить изменения сразу в несколько репозиториев, написано, например, [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14290145/4827341) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3195446/4827341). и по-русски: [Отправить изменения в несколько репозиториев одной командой push](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/499738/178576)

Comment: Вот как попробовал сделать, как на самом сайте:

    `cd /path/to/my/repo;
    git remote add bb https://vtvz@bitbucket.org/vtvz/wertewrt.git;
    git push -u bb --all;`

И, вместо того, чтобы создать ветку master, он мне создал основную ветку bb. Я не знаю, почему это происходило, но когда я попробовал еще раз, все получилось, как надо. А в некоторых случая писал, что все вообще отлично, супер и работает.
У меня как раз были трудности в **первом** пуше на сервер битбакета.

Comment: Я все таки лучше буду еще пушить на еще один локальный репозиторий, как я делал раньше. Пусть лучше будет еще один бекап. А то я уже как-то накосячил с конфигами того и пришлось все удалить и сделать опять clone